# tcsh shell script gives "command not found" even for var=value

Tags: shell, tcsh

I am trying to write a simple shell script which I execute via tcsh ./renameTool

It works for

```
#!/bin/tcsh
# Variablen
echo "MYVAR is"
```

but not for

```
#!/bin/tcsh
# Variablen
MYVAR="hi there"
echo "MYVAR is: $MYVAR"
```

I get the error:
MYVAR=hi there: Command not found.
MYVAR: Undefined variable

I already checked for any spaces when declaring the variable. No change...

Can you help me?

Thank you :-)

Lucas

Comment: `tcsh` is not `bash`; it's a completely different shell from an incompatible family. Tag for the shell you're actually using (and be sure you write scripts with that shell's syntax/language).

Comment: ...by the way, if you can at all avoid it, you absolutely _shouldn't_ choose to use tcsh, or any other csh-family shell. There are several classic essays on the topic -- https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt among them -- but the bottom line is that it's a poorly-designed language, and back in 1992 POSIX standardized on a language from the Bourne family (with additional inspiration from ksh) as POSIX sh, the standard with which bash complies. There's no excuse to still be using anything from the csh family decades after the standard decision went elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set MYVAR = "hi there"
echo "MYVAR is: $MYVAR"
```

Comment: It is good, if you add some explanations. It helps understanding why your example works (by people who look for such question, which possibly are not `tcsh` users